# Tidy Data: Rename columns, get non-NA column names, then gather

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr, dplyr

I've got a rather ugly bit of data to tidy up and need help! What my data look like now:

```
countries <- c("Austria", "Belgium", "Croatia")

df <- tibble("age" = c(28,42,19, 67),
         "1_recreate_1"=c(NA,15,NA,NA), 
         "1_recreate_2"=c(NA,10,NA,NA), 
         "1_recreate_3"=c(NA,8,NA,NA),
         "1_recreate_4"=c(NA,4,NA,NA),
         "1_fairness" = c(NA, 7, NA, NA),
         "1_confidence" = c(NA, 5, NA, NA),
         "2_recreate_1"=c(29,NA,NA,30),
         "2_recreate_2"=c(20,NA,NA,24),
         "2_recreate_3"=c(15,NA,NA,15),
         "2_recreate_4"=c(11,NA,NA,9),
         "2_fairness" = c(4, NA, NA, 1),
         "2_confidence" = c(5, NA, NA, 4),
         "3_recreate_1"=c(NA,NA,50,NA), 
         "3_recreate_2"=c(NA,NA,40,NA), 
         "3_recreate_3"=c(NA,NA,30,NA),
         "3_recreate_4"=c(NA,NA,20,NA),
         "3_fairness" = c(NA,  NA, 2, NA),
         "3_confidence" = c(NA, NA, 2, NA),
         "overall" = c(3,3,2,5))
```

What I need them to look like at the end (hard-coding it):

```
df <- tibble(age = rep(c(28,42,19,67), each=4),
         country = rep(c("Belgium", "Austria", "Croatia", "Belgium"), each=4),
         recreate = rep(1:4, times=4),
         fairness = rep(c(4,7,2,1), each=4),
         confidence = rep(c(5,5,2,4), each=4),     
         allocation = c(29, 20, 15, 11,
                        15, 10, 8, 4,
                        50, 40, 30, 20, 
                        30, 24, 15, 9),
         overall = rep(c(3,3,2,5), each=4))
```

Steps to get there (I think!):

**1. Replace the starting numbers for those columns using my list of countries.**
The number that starts the string is the index in `countries`. In other words, `16_recreate_1` would correspond with the 16th country in the vector `countries`. I think the following code works (though am not sure it's exactly right):

```
for(i in length(countries):1){
    colnames(df) <- str_replace(colnames(df), paste0(i,"_"), paste0(countries[i],"_"))
}
```

**2. Create a new variable called "country" by getting the name of the column(s) that is NOT NA for each row.**

I tried a BUNCH of experimentation with `which.max` and `names`, but couldn't get it fully functional.

**3. Create new variables (`recreate_1`...`recreate_4`) that grab the `[country_name]_recreate_1`...`[country_name]_recreate_4` value for each row, whatever country is non-NA for that person.**

Maybe `rowSums` is the way to do this?

**4. Make the data long instead of wide**
I think this is going to require `gather`, but I'm not sure how to gather from only the variables `country` and `recreate_1`...`recreate_4`.

I'm so sorry this is so complex. Tidyverse solutions are preferred but any help is *greatly* appreciated!

Comment: Woops! Sorry about that--updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somehow different `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 gather(variable, allocation, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
 separate(variable, c("ID", "variable", "recreate"), convert = TRUE) %>%
 left_join(data.frame(countries) %>%
            mutate(country = countries,
                   ID = seq_along(countries)) %>%
            select(-countries), by = c("ID" = "ID")) %>%
 select(-variable, -ID) 

   recreate allocation country
      <int>      <dbl> <fct>  
 1        1         15 Austria
 2        2         10 Austria
 3        3          8 Austria
 4        4          4 Austria
 5        1         29 Belgium
 6        1         30 Belgium
 7        2         20 Belgium
 8        2         24 Belgium
 9        3         15 Belgium
10        3         15 Belgium
11        4         11 Belgium
12        4          9 Belgium
13        1         50 Croatia
14        2         40 Croatia
15        3         30 Croatia
16        4         20 Croatia
```

Here it, first, transforms the data from wide to long format, removing the rows with NA. Second, it separates the variable names into three columns. Third, it transforms the vector of countries into a df and assigns each country a unique ID. Finally, it joins the two and removes the redundant variables.

A solution to the edited question:

```
df %>%
 select(matches("(recreate)")) %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, allocation, -rowid, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
 separate(var, c("ID", "var", "recreate"), convert = TRUE) %>%
 select(-var) %>%
 left_join(data.frame(countries) %>%
            mutate(country = countries,
                   ID = seq_along(countries)) %>%
            select(-countries), by = c("ID" = "ID")) %>% 
 left_join(df %>%
            select(-matches("(recreate)")) %>%
            rowid_to_column() %>%
            gather(var, val, -rowid, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
            mutate(var = gsub("[^[:alpha:]]", "", var)) %>%
            spread(var, val), by = c("rowid" = "rowid")) %>%
 select(-rowid, -ID)

   recreate allocation country   age confidence fairness overall
      <int>      <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
 1        1         15 Austria    42          5        7       3
 2        2         10 Austria    42          5        7       3
 3        3          8 Austria    42          5        7       3
 4        4          4 Austria    42          5        7       3
 5        1         29 Belgium    28          5        4       3
 6        1         30 Belgium    67          4        1       5
 7        2         20 Belgium    28          5        4       3
 8        2         24 Belgium    67          4        1       5
 9        3         15 Belgium    28          5        4       3
10        3         15 Belgium    67          4        1       5
11        4         11 Belgium    28          5        4       3
12        4          9 Belgium    67          4        1       5
13        1         50 Croatia    19          2        2       2
14        2         40 Croatia    19          2        2       2
15        3         30 Croatia    19          2        2       2
16        4         20 Croatia    19          2        2       2
```

Here it, first, selects the columns that contain `recreate` and adds a columns with row ID. Second, it follows the steps from the original solution. Third, it selects the columns that do not contain `recreate`, performs a wide-to-long data transformation, removes the number from column names and transforms the data back to the original wide format. Finally, it joins the two on row ID and removes the redundant variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% mutate(rid=row_number()) %>% 
       gather(key,val,-c(age,overall,rid, matches('recreate'))) %>% mutate(country=sub('(^\\d)_.*','\\1',key),country=countries[as.numeric(country)]) %>% 
       filter(!is.na(val)) %>% mutate(key=sub('(^\\d\\_)(.*)','\\2',key)) %>%
       spread(key,val) %>% gather(key = recreate,value = allocation,-c(rid,age,overall,Country,confidence,fairness)) %>% 
       filter(!is.na(allocation)) %>% mutate(recreate=sub('.*_(\\d$)','\\1',recreate))
```

Here `(^\\d)_.*` means get the first digit while `.*_(\\d$)` means get the last digit.

Comment: This is outrageously impressive--SO efficient. Thanks, Suliman!

Comment: 2 Qs:  
1.  I have about a dozen variables (e.g. `name`, `age` etc.) before & another dozen after the list of `1_recreate_1`... variables that get thrown out w/ this code. How do I preserve them in the new `gather`ed data? 

2. I also have variables called, `1_confidence` and `1_fairness` that I want to do the same thing as for `1_recreate_1` but they don't end in `_#`. How can I grab those (to create a new variable called `confidence` and `fairness`)? 

I left both out of my original question, thinking I'd figure it out, but I'm getting lost in the `sub` & regex. I edited the original.